# "Scope Highlight" feature in Visual Studio? (same as seen in BlueJ for java)

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, ide, options-menu

I would like to know (as I've failed so far in finding such a feature in the VS's options),
if there is a feature which allow for scope highlighting same as seen in the BlueJ IDE for java,
here is an example:

[image]

Note how the code blocks are all highlighted with color,
when learning java using blueJ i found it to be extremely easy on the eye when looking at code,
and everything felt a lot more organized,
moving to C# and working on MS visual studio, its all text with some highlighting, Class names, keywords etc etc,
but in general it still feel like a black text on a white background and lacking that organized feeling i sorely miss from blueJ,

i noticed there is a similar question here referring to eclipse,
[Eclipse IDE Scope Highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820952/eclipse-ide-scope-highlighting)

just to be on the safe side, ill ask again referring to Visual studio,
is there such a feature in VS? is there an add-on \ plugin for VS which allows it?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the DevExpress CodeRush plugin, there is a 30-day trial version.
The function it provides is called "Structural highlighting", and I think its even better than what you want (and its customizable).

[CodeRush Express](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/F9CDA5D8-10AF-4CC6-9D17-207222A3FD13)

[CodeRush Documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument3535)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft provides a free Productivity Power Tools extension for Visual Studio 2013 and 2015. This has a "Structure Visualizer" feature similar to the CodeRush plugin. Both are more subtle than the BlueJ style, but should make scopes a little clearer.

[image: screenshot]

[Productivity Power Tools 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)

[Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)

**Update**

Visual Studio 2017 integrated a version of this into the core application for C#, Visual Basic, F#, and XAML (as [Structure Guide Lines](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0#a-idbetternav-aimproved-code-navigation)). However, C++ still requires an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.StructureVisualizer).