# “Scope Highlight” feature in Visual Studio? (same as seen in BlueJ for java)

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I would like to know (as I've failed so far in finding such a feature in the Visual Studio's options), if there is a feature which allow for scope highlighting same as seen in the BlueJ IDE for java?

Here is an example:

[image]

Note how the code blocks are all highlighted with color,
when learning java using blueJ I found it to be extremely easy on the eye when looking at code, and everything felt a lot more organized, moving to C# and working on Visual Studio, its all text with some highlighting, Class names, keywords etc., but in general it still feel like a black text on a white background and lacking that organized feeling i sorely miss from blueJ,

Is there such a feature in Visual Studio? Is there an add-on \ plugin for VS which allows it? I'm aware of structure visualizer (guide lines), that's not what I want.

Comment: yes, I'm aware this is copied from a 4-year-old question. (that is copied from a 5 year old question.)

Comment: see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using some tool. Such questions are on topic only if they cover how the tool integrates into some development *process* – after all, this site is about Software Engineering. See our [help/on-topic] for details. Please read: [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7253) Usage of development tools is on topic on Stack Overflow. For general purpose tools go to Super User.

Comment: @LouisHong the idea of questions appropriate to a particular forum is so that people interested in or with expertise in an area will be congregating within that forum. So posting the question in the appropriate forum increases the probability that someone with expertise will see your posting and will be able to provide an answer. Posting a question in the appropriate forum also provides a way for other people with a similar question to be able to find your posting which will hopefully have a useful answer.

Comment: What @RichardChambers said, with the caveat that these aren't actually "forums," and so you can't assume that any of the rules that apply to forums also apply here.

Comment: In addition, you have a much higher chance of being treated like a professional here if you structure your posts in a professional way (see my edits).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Scope Highlight" feature in Visual Studio? (same as seen in BlueJ for java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129454/scope-highlight-feature-in-visual-studio-same-as-seen-in-bluej-for-java)